# Define with curly braces

Tags: c

I've been trying to look up information on this to no avail. Can someone explain what the curly braces do here? I'm trying to find or create the ISR function for the transmit/receive IRQ, however I am stuck here.

```
/** Interrupt vectors for the ENET peripheral type */
#define ENET_Transmit_IRQS                       { ENET_Transmit_IRQn }
#define ENET_Receive_IRQS                        { ENET_Receive_IRQn }
```

In this case `ENET_Transmit_IRQn` is the 83rd vector in the IRQ vector and the Rx is consecutively, 84th.

What are the curly braces for? My only logical argument is that these vectors are in a typedef enum IRQ (structure? It doesn't say struct though), and essentially it is the same as

```
#define ENET_Transmit_IRQS 83
```

P.S. This is for a Kinetis K66

EDIT: I just found 1 line where it is being used.

```
/*! @brief Pointers to enet transmit IRQ number for each instance. */
static const IRQn_Type s_enetTxIrqId[] = ENET_Transmit_IRQS;
```

Where `IRQn_Type` is

```
typedef enum IRQn {
...
  ENET_1588_Timer_IRQn         = 82,               /**< Ethernet MAC IEEE 1588 Timer Interrupt */
  ENET_Transmit_IRQn           = 83,               /**< Ethernet MAC Transmit Interrupt */
  ENET_Receive_IRQn            = 84,               /**< Ethernet MAC Receive Interrupt */
  ENET_Error_IRQn              = 85,               /**< Ethernet MAC Error and miscelaneous Interrupt */
...
} IRQn_Type;
```

Comment: Look where this macro is used. Then substitute it with this macro body and see which sense does it make.

Comment: They don't "do" anything, they are part of the text replacement that the pre-processor does.

Comment: ENET_Transmit_IRQS is not used anywhere, and ENET_Transmint_IRQn is defined in the IRQ vector list.

Comment: If it is not used, then it is literally doing nothing.

Comment: So what are the curly braces doing? Aside from not doing anything, if i delete the braces i get an error "invalid initializer"

Comment: Then it *is* used. Look again. (The sentence "what is it doing aside of not doing anything" is pretty absurd, don't you think?)

Comment: If you cannot interprete the useage, then show it and we might try.

Comment: OK, now you have found the usage. Replace the macro name with macro body. This is what preprocessor does.

Comment: The preprocessor is just slapping an 83 in the s_enetTxIrqId[]?

Comment: No, replacing `ENET_Transmit_IRQn` with 83 is the compiler's job.

Comment: Ah, ENET_Transmit_IRQn is going there then?

Comment: In curly braces, apparently. As an array initializer should be.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. If I take the "[]" off then I should have no need for the braces? The library is setup to have multiple ethernets with multiple IRQ for each one, etc. I've assuming that's why most variables are arrays.

Comment: Then you will probably break something elsewhere

Comment: Right, just in theory though, to understand this concept. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When @EugeneSh. said _"it is literally doing nothing"_ he was referring to the whole macro, not the braces - if the macro is not used, it is not used.  However if by changing it you get an error then it quite clearly is used - exactly where the error is reported.  Macros do not themselves cause errors; the context in which they are used can cause errors if the resulting expansion results in invalid code.  Even though you have answered your own question, it would still be useful to edit your question to show that usage - or add that to your answer even.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand this now with the help of Eugene (thanks!!). It has curly braces because it is being used as an initializer for an array.